# Получить значение src из функции?

Tags: php

Извиняйте, если не корректно сформировал вопрос.
Суть следующая, есть вот такой код:

```
foreach($group AS $product){
if (isset($product['group_title']) && $product['group_title']) {
$group_id++;
...
if ($parametri["show_image"] == 1) {
if (isset($product['images'])) {
$firsttime = true;
echo '<td class="cell_image">';
foreach ($product['images'] as $image) {
if ($firsttime) {
echo $image->displayMediaThumb('class="product-image"', true, 'rel="catproduct_images_'.$i.'"', true, false);
$firsttime = false;
} else {
echo '<a title="'.$image->product_name.'" rel="catproduct_images_0" href="'.$image->file_url.'"></a>';
}
}
echo '</td>';
}
else {
echo '<td class="cell_image"></td>';
}
}
...
$i++;
```

Он генерирует html строки с изображением.
Мне нужно вытащить из него SRC картинки. Как это сделать ума не приложу, вроде бы просто, ан нет...
Помогите разобраться...
Заранее благодарю за ответ

```
<td class="cell_image"><a title="fMEWGS151041" rel="catproduct_images_0" href="https://makcon.ru/images/stories/virtuemart/product/fMEWGS151041.jpg"><img src="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg" alt="fMEWGS151041" class="product-image" /></a></td>
```

Comment: добавил кусок кода

Comment: сделал, вот так генерит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если картинка одна, то можно вытащить ссылку из атрибута src с помощью **[preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)**:

```
$str = '<td class="cell_image"><a title="fMEWGS151041" rel="catproduct_images_0" href="https://makcon.ru/images/stories/virtuemart/product/fMEWGS151041.jpg"><img src="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg" alt="fMEWGS151041" class="product-image" /></a></td>';

preg_match('~(?<=src=")[^"]+(?=")~', $str, $arr);
$img = $arr[0] ?? '';

echo $img;
```

В результате будет строка:

```
/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg
```

---

Если на входе у вас массив, то нужно обрабатывать его в цикле *(или подходящими php-функциями)*, проверяя каждый элемент массива на наличие атрибута `src="..."`. Так как в результате уточняющих комментариев не выяснилось, что именно нужно обрабатывать *(строку или массив)*, то я решил написать универсальную функцию, которая будет принимать на вход строку или массив, а в результате возвращать всегда массив *(если совпадений не найдено - пустой массив)*. Код функции:

```
function get_url($images, $img = []): Array
{
    $pcre = function($html)use(&$img){
        preg_match('~(?<=src=")[^"]+(?=")~', $html, $arr);
        empty($arr[0]) ?: $img[] = $arr[0];
    };

    if (is_array($images)) {
        foreach ($images as $html) {
            $pcre($html);
        }
    } else {
        $pcre($images);
    }

    return $img;
}
```

Пример использования для массива:

```
$images = [
    '<p><img src="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg" /></p>',
    '<p><img src="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg" /></p>',
    '<p><img src="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg" /></p>',
    '<img src="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg" />',
    '<img src="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg" />'
];

var_dump( get_url($images) );
```

Результат:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string '/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg' (length=64)
  1 => string '/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg' (length=64)
  2 => string '/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg' (length=64)
  3 => string '/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg' (length=64)
  4 => string '/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg' (length=64)
```

Пример использования для строки:

```
$image = '<p><img src="/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg" /></p>';

var_dump( get_url($image) );
```

Результат:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/fMEWGS151041_0x80.jpg' (length=64)
```

---

В контексте вашего кода использование будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
// Объявить мвссив
$images = [];

foreach ($group AS $product) {
    if (isset($product['group_title']) && $product['group_title']) {
        $group_id++;

        if ($parametri["show_image"] == 1) {
            if (isset($product['images'])) {
                $firsttime = true;
                echo '<td class="cell_image">';
                foreach ($product['images'] as $image) {
                    if ($firsttime) {

                        // Сохранить результат из метода во временную переменную $temp
                        $temp = $image->displayMediaThumb('class="product-image"', true, 'rel="catproduct_images_'.$i.'"', true, false);

                        // Передать переменную в get_url(), и получить массив
                        $images[] = get_url($temp);

                        $firsttime = false;
                    } else {
                        echo '<a title="'.$image->product_name.'" rel="catproduct_images_0" href="'.$image->file_url.'"></a>';
                    }
                }
                echo '</td>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<td class="cell_image"></td>';
            }
        }

        $i++;
    }
}

// Просмотр полученного массива
var_dump( $images );
```

Comment: ага, с помощью регулярных выражений, так?
Вот куда этот код ставить?
Да, картинка одна, но она в массиве, т.е. 1 в строке, а в массиве N-кол-во строк

Comment: @Макс ну если html много, то лучше с помощью какой-то подходящей библиотеки: DOM, Simple HTML Dom, PhpQuery, и т.п. ... На счёт массива - вы ведь в примере написали строку, я для строки и написал решение. Более того, в вашем коде запись `echo $image->displayMediaThumb(...)` не может возвращать массив, иначе какой тогда смысл в использовании оператора `echo`? Но если всё-таки у вас массив, то опубликуйте его в вашем первом посту _(отредактируйте его)_, и я дополню свой ответ.

Comment: выложил полный массив php кода, конечно где "..." там много еще кода, который не влияет на вопрос
Я хочу в этом же файле вытащить из функции displayMediaThumb SRC картинки, если это возможно...

Comment: @Макс тяжело однако с вами :) ... Попробую ещё раз -- мне не нужен ваш php-код, мне нужен ваш массив данных, которые подлежат обработке, т.е., нужен массив, в котором хранится набор html-кода, среди которого есть те картинки, урлы которых вы хотите получить. В принципе, можете не писать ваш массив - я просто напишу функцию, которая будет получать урлы и возвращать массив этих урлов.

Comment: извините за мою недалекость...
просто, если бы я понимал как и куда копать пошел бы просто копать )))
мозг сломал, вот и прошу помощи...
а, " массив, в котором хранится набор html-кода, " это строка выше, там просто (rel="catproduct_images_0") меняется на (..._1, ..._2 и т.д.) ну сами данные "SRC" и "ALT"

Comment: спасибо!
а куда вставлять функцию? ваще не понимаю

Comment: @Макс куда угодно, туда и вставляйте. Обычно есть файл с набором 
пользовательских функций, который подключается _(инклудится)_ к основному скрипту. Если у вас нет такого файла с функциями, то можете мою функцию вставить прямо в вашем файле, где-то в нижней его части.

Comment: функцию вставил вставил с конец того же файла и обернул в <script>. Но, к сожалению код "$images[] = get_url($temp);" ломает сайт, ему явно не нравится что то... Простите меня за "тупость"

Answer (score 0):

Эх, а ларчик просто открывался )))
Суть решения была на поверхности, а именно:

```
echo '<a title="'.$image->product_name.'" rel="catproduct_images_0" href="'.$image->file_url.'"></a>';
```

}

тут есть href="'.$image->file_url.'" это и есть ключ к победе )))

```
$img_src = "/".$image->file_url;
```

написал вот так чтобы получить путь к картинке
далее, был обработчик РАДИО переключатель к нему добавил это:

```
data-imag="'.$img_src.'"
```

затем пошел в JS файл обработчика событий радио-переключателя и там:

```
var d_img = checkboxes[index].getAttribute('data-imag');
```

получил атрибут ссылки, далее вернул куда мне надо было, вот так:

```
document.querySelector('img[class="info_cpu"]').setAttribute('src', d_img);
```

что получил:
при клике на радио, вывел инфу о выборе + картинку, для наглядности ссылка на сайт:
https://makcon.ru/catalog/create-pc
кому интересно, нажмите на иконку над словом "Процессоры" и покликайте на радио переключатели...

- Огромное спасибо терпеливому форумчанину под ником "Эдуард"...